# Java SHA256 outputs different hash to PHP SHA256?

Tags: java, php, hash, sha256

PHP code:

`echo hash('sha256', 'jake');`

PHP output:

cdf30c6b345276278bedc7bcedd9d5582f5b8e0c1dd858f46ef4ea231f92731d

Java code:

```
String s = "jake";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
byte[] hashed = md.digest();
String s2 = "";
for (byte b : hashed) {
    s2 += b;
}
System.out.println(s2);
```

Java output:

-51-1312107528211839-117-19-57-68-19-39-43884791-1141229-4088-12110-12-223531-11011529

I had expected the two to return the same result. Obviously, this is not the case. How can I get the two to match up or is it impossible?

EDIT: I had made a mistake, think I have the answer to the question now anyway.

Comment: Check your character encoding - PHP works with bytes, does Java use UTF8 or UTF16 (or what)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the *very first* thing you need to do is use a consistent string encoding. I've no idea what PHP will do, but `"jake".getBytes()` will use whatever your platform default encoding is for Java. That's a *really bad idea*. Using UTF-8 would probably be a good start, assuming that PHP copes with Unicode strings to start with. (If it doesn't, you'll need to work out what it *is* doing and try to make the two consistent.) In Java, use the overload of `String.getBytes()` which takes a `Charset` or the one which takes the name of a `Charset`. (Personally I like to use Guava's `Charsets.UTF_8`.)

Then persuade PHP to use UTF-8 as well.

Then output the Java result in hex. I very much doubt that the code you've given is the actual code you're running, as otherwise I'd expect output such as "[B@e48e1b". Whatever you're doing to convert the byte array into a string, change it to use hex.

Comment: Python tends to use ISO-8859-1, but is trying to adopt Unicode, so this may depend on the version. For `'jake'`, an all-ASCII string, this should yield the same as UTF-8. Nevertheless, I warmly second the consistent string encoding requirement.

Comment: @Thomas: Yup - I felt it was important to get that right *first*, before the rest... because otherwise, as soon as the OP saw a "working" digest (e.g. just by converting his existing byte array to hex) they might well decide to declare victory :)

Answer (score 6):

They are printing the same .. convert your byte[] to a hex string, then you'll see CDF30C6B345276278BEDC7BCEDD9D5582F5B8E0C1DD858F46EF4EA231F92731D as Java output, too:

```
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update("jake".getBytes());
    System.out.println(getHex(md.digest()));
}

static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";
public static String getHex( byte [] raw ) {
    if ( raw == null ) {
      return null;
    }
    final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder( 2 * raw.length );
    for ( final byte b : raw ) {
      hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
         .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the digest to a HEX string before printing it out. Example code can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/).