# NodeJS - SHA256 Password Encryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I'm currently learning about encryption and password safety in NodeJS. I'm working with a current example that currently is using PBKDF2, I'd like to switch this out to use SHA256 instead. Is this possible and/or make sense? How would I go about it?

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var len = 128;

var iterations = 13000;

module.exports = function (pwd, salt, fn) {
  if (3 == arguments.length) {
    crypto.pbkdf2(pwd, salt, iterations, len, fn);
  } else {
    fn = salt;
    crypto.randomBytes(len, function(err, salt){
      if (err) return fn(err);
      salt = salt.toString('base64');
      crypto.pbkdf2(pwd, salt, iterations, len, function(err, hash){
        if (err) return fn(err);
        fn(null, salt, hash);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714103/hashing-a-password-using-sha256-and-net-node-js

Comment: This is a fairly good summary of password hashing: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha256 Check this module

Comment: _Please_ do not use sha256 for password hashing https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If wanted to generate `sha256` hashes, then you'd have to drop the iterations and length property as those are specific to `pbkdf2`. You would then use `crypto.createHash()` which uses OpenSSL to generate hashes. That being said, the types of hashes you can generate are dependent on the version of OpenSSL that you have installed.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(pwd).digest('base64');
```

Your specific implementation might look like this:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
module.exports = function(pwd, fn) {
  var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(pwd).digest('base64');
  fn(null, hash);
};
```

Comment: Actually to generate a password hashed in sha256, you have to use digest 'hex':
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(pwd).digest('hex');

Comment: The hash is still `sha256`, it's just in a different encoding. The person who asked the question also used `base64` as his encoding, therefore, I answered like so.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that I guess some people don't manage encoding and want a result in basic SHA256 (such as me), I used some time to understand it so I just wanted to help for the nexts :p

Comment: Hi, This is nothing but encryption. Can you please let me know how to decrypt?.

Comment: Hi @user740189,

`SHA` is a one way algorithm, a hashing algorithm. It is not meant to be reversed and can't be. A hashing algorithm is meant to represent data in a unique way. It is not meant to store data.