# JavaScript: How to generate Rfc2898DeriveBytes like C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-identity, cryptojs, rfc2898

**EDIT:** Per discussion in the comments, let me clarify that this will be happening server side, behind SSL. I do not intend to expose the hashed password or the hashing scheme to the client.

Assume we have an existing asp.net identity database with the default tables (aspnet_Users, aspnet_Roles, etc.). Based on my understanding, the password hashing algorithm uses sha256 and stores the salt + (hashed password) as a base64 encoded string. ***EDIT: This assumption is incorrect, see answer below.***

I would like to replicate the function of the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Crypto class' [VerifyHashedPassword](https://gist.github.com/trailmax/553ea84d4d0e2e20fcd7) function with a JavaScript version.

Let's say that a password is **welcome1** and its asp.net hashed password is        **ADOEtXqGCnWCuuc5UOAVIvMVJWjANOA/LoVy0E4XCyUHIfJ7dfSY0Id+uJ20DTtG+A==**

So far I have been able to reproduce the parts of the method that get the salt and the stored sub key.

Where the C# implementation does more or less this:

```
var salt = new byte[SaltSize];
Buffer.BlockCopy(hashedPasswordBytes, 1, salt, 0, SaltSize);
var storedSubkey = new byte[PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
Buffer.BlockCopy(hashedPasswordBytes, 1 + SaltSize, storedSubkey, 0, PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
```

I have the following in JavaScript (not elegant by any stretch):

```
var hashedPwd = "ADOEtXqGCnWCuuc5UOAVIvMVJWjANOA/LoVy0E4XCyUHIfJ7dfSY0Id+uJ20DTtG+A==";
var hashedPasswordBytes = new Buffer(hashedPwd, 'base64');
var saltbytes = [];
var storedSubKeyBytes = [];

for(var i=1;i<hashedPasswordBytes.length;i++)
{
  if(i > 0 && i <= 16)
  {
    saltbytes.push(hashedPasswordBytes[i]);
  }
  if(i > 0 && i >16) {
    storedSubKeyBytes.push(hashedPasswordBytes[i]);
  }
}
```

Again, it ain't pretty, but after running this snippet the saltbytes and storedSubKeyBytes match byte for byte what I see in the C# debugger for salt and storedSubkey.

Finally, in C#, an instance of Rfc2898DeriveBytes is used to generate a new subkey based on the salt and the password provided, like so:

```
byte[] generatedSubkey;
using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, PBKDF2IterCount))
{
   generatedSubkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. I have tried others' solutions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745974/how-to-check-asp-net-password-hash-in-node-js), I have used Google's and Node's CryptoJS and crypto libraries respectively, and my output never generates anything resembling the C# version.

(Example:

```
var output = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer('welcome1', 'utf16le'), 
    new Buffer(parsedSaltString), 1000, 32, 'sha256');
console.log(output.toString('base64'))
```

generates "LSJvaDM9u7pXRfIS7QDFnmBPvsaN2z7FMXURGHIuqdY=")

Many of the pointers I've found online indicate problems involving encoding mismatches (NodeJS / UTF-8 vs. .NET / UTF-16LE), so I've tried encoding using the default .NET encoding format but to no avail.

Or I could be completely wrong about what I assume these libraries are doing. But any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to generate password hash on the client and pass the hash down to the server for validation?

Comment: No, I'm trying to generate the hash server side in node.js. Essentially, keeping the database the same but swapping out the IIS / asp.net layer for node. I'm not a security expert but I would be wary of trying to do any password operations client side.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies my concerns. I'd mention this in your question. Sorry, can't actually help with JS-side of things here(

Comment: @trailmax Could you please explain your concerns with client-side hashing a little further?

Comment: @bonh See this explanation http://security.stackexchange.com/a/53606

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I think this problem ended up being quite a bit simpler than I was making it (aren't they always). After performing a RTFM operation on the [pbkdf2 spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt), I ran some side-by-side tests with Node crypto and .NET crypto, and have made pretty good progress on a solution.

The following JavaScript code correctly parses the stored salt and subkey, then verifies the given password by hashing it with the stored salt. There are doubtless better / cleaner / more secure tweaks, so comments welcome.

```
// NodeJS implementation of crypto, I'm sure google's 
// cryptoJS would work equally well.
var crypto = require('crypto');

// The value stored in [dbo].[AspNetUsers].[PasswordHash]
var hashedPwd = "ADOEtXqGCnWCuuc5UOAVIvMVJWjANOA/LoVy0E4XCyUHIfJ7dfSY0Id+uJ20DTtG+A==";
var hashedPasswordBytes = new Buffer(hashedPwd, 'base64');

var hexChar = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

var saltString = "";
var storedSubKeyString = "";

// build strings of octets for the salt and the stored key
for (var i = 1; i < hashedPasswordBytes.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i <= 16) {
        saltString += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f]
    }
    if (i > 0 && i > 16) {
        storedSubKeyString += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f];
    }
}

// password provided by the user
var password = 'welcome1';

// TODO remove debug - logging passwords in prod is considered 
// tasteless for some odd reason
console.log('cleartext: ' + password);
console.log('saltString: ' + saltString);
console.log('storedSubKeyString: ' + storedSubKeyString);

// This is where the magic happens. 
// If you are doing your own hashing, you can (and maybe should)
// perform more iterations of applying the salt and perhaps
// use a stronger hash than sha1, but if you want it to work
// with the [as of 2015] Microsoft Identity framework, keep
// these settings.
var nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer(password), new Buffer(saltString, 'hex'), 1000, 256, 'sha1');

// get a hex string of the derived bytes
var derivedKeyOctets = nodeCrypto.toString('hex').toUpperCase();

console.log("hex of derived key octets: " + derivedKeyOctets);

// The first 64 bytes of the derived key should
// match the stored sub key
if (derivedKeyOctets.indexOf(storedSubKeyString) === 0) {
    console.info("passwords match!");
} else {
    console.warn("passwords DO NOT match!");
}
```

Comment: You sir have just saved my life. Thanks a lot.
I'm migrating from ASP.NET to node.js and now I don't have to tell my users their password has expired! :D

Comment: If you let me, I will post some keywords so someone like me can find this easier in the future:
SimpleMembershipProviider hash algorythm ASP.NET MVC password hashing compare

Comment: Sure thing... what do I need to do to help post the keywords?

Comment: Oh, nothing, I just thought google can now crawl in here and relate this thread with those keywords.

Comment: This also saved the day for my ASP.Net to Node project conversion as well! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I see this is to compare a known hash to its source for logging in. I also need to be able to create and update passwords going forward. Have you figured out that part? Seems to be that the Rfc2898DeriveBytes method in C# is what generates a salt based on the source password, but it eventually calls a DLL so I'm not sure if it can be reproduced in Node.

Comment: I ended up writing this as a node module here: https://github.com/CmdrShepardsPie/JavaScript-Helpers/blob/master/node-password-hashing.js

Comment: @GojiraDeMonstah Thank you! Working on a Node app that needs to use existing .Net db for authentication purposes, this is exactly what I needed. I'd upvote twice if I could ;)

Comment: @GojiraDeMonstah Thank you sir greatly for saving my life :D

Comment: It does not completely work. if u use `source` as the password and `hash` as the hashed password, this function returns true while it should return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option which actually compares the bytes as opposed to converting to a string representation.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const password = 'Password123';
const storedHashString = 'J9IBFSw0U1EFsH/ysL+wak6wb8s=';
const storedSaltString = '2nX0MZPZlwiW8bYLlVrfjBYLBKM=';

const storedHashBytes = new Buffer.from(storedHashString, 'base64');
const storedSaltBytes = new Buffer.from(storedSaltString, 'base64');

crypto.pbkdf2(password, storedSaltBytes, 1000, 20, 'sha1',
  (err, calculatedHashBytes) => {
    const correct = calculatedHashBytes.equals(storedHashBytes);
    console.log('Password is ' + (correct ? 'correct ' : 'incorrect '));
  }
);
```

1000 is the default number of iterations in **System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes** and 20 is the number of bytes we are using to store the salt (again the default).

Comment: Probably way better than what I was doing. I was just grasping at straws trying to understand the basic sequence of steps.

Comment: I used emojis too

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution will not work in all cases.
Let's say that you want to compare a password `source` against a hash in the database `hash`, which can be technically possible if the database is compromised, then the function will return `true` because the subkey is an empty string.

Modify the function to catch that up and return false instead.

```
// NodeJS implementation of crypto, I'm sure google's 
// cryptoJS would work equally well.
var crypto = require('crypto');

// The value stored in [dbo].[AspNetUsers].[PasswordHash]
var hashedPwd = "ADOEtXqGCnWCuuc5UOAVIvMVJWjANOA/LoVy0E4XCyUHIfJ7dfSY0Id+uJ20DTtG+A==";
var hashedPasswordBytes = new Buffer(hashedPwd, 'base64');

var hexChar = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

var saltString = "";
var storedSubKeyString = "";

// build strings of octets for the salt and the stored key
for (var i = 1; i < hashedPasswordBytes.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i <= 16) {
        saltString += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f]
    }
    if (i > 0 && i > 16) {
        storedSubKeyString += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f];
    }
}

if (storedSubKeyString === '') { return false }

// password provided by the user
var password = 'welcome1';

// TODO remove debug - logging passwords in prod is considered 
// tasteless for some odd reason
console.log('cleartext: ' + password);
console.log('saltString: ' + saltString);
console.log('storedSubKeyString: ' + storedSubKeyString);

// This is where the magic happens. 
// If you are doing your own hashing, you can (and maybe should)
// perform more iterations of applying the salt and perhaps
// use a stronger hash than sha1, but if you want it to work
// with the [as of 2015] Microsoft Identity framework, keep
// these settings.
var nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer(password), new Buffer(saltString, 'hex'), 1000, 256, 'sha1');

// get a hex string of the derived bytes
var derivedKeyOctets = nodeCrypto.toString('hex').toUpperCase();

console.log("hex of derived key octets: " + derivedKeyOctets);

// The first 64 bytes of the derived key should
// match the stored sub key
if (derivedKeyOctets.indexOf(storedSubKeyString) === 0) {
    console.info("passwords match!");
} else {
    console.warn("passwords DO NOT match!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is rather late, but I ran into an issue with reproducing C#'s Rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes in Node, and kept coming back to this SO answer. I ended up creating a minimal class for my own usage, and I figured I'd share in case someone else was having the same issues. It's not perfect, but it works.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const $key = Symbol('key');
const $saltSize = Symbol('saltSize');
const $salt = Symbol('salt');
const $iterationCount = Symbol('iterationCount');
const $position = Symbol('position');

class Rfc2898DeriveBytes {
    constructor(key, saltSize = 32, iterationCount = 1000) {
        this[$key] = key;
        this[$saltSize] = saltSize;
        this[$iterationCount] = iterationCount;
        this[$position] = 0;
        this[$salt] = crypto.randomBytes(this[$saltSize]);
    }

    get salt() {
        return this[$salt];
    }
    set salt(buffer) {
        this[$salt] = buffer;
    }

    get iterationCount() {
        return this[$iterationCount];
    }
    set iterationCount(count) {
        this[$iterationCount] = count;
    }

    getBytes(byteCount) {
        let position = this[$position];
        let bytes = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(Buffer.from(this[$key]), this.salt, this.iterationCount, position + byteCount, 'sha1');
        this[$position] += byteCount;
        let result = Buffer.alloc(byteCount);
        for (let i = 0; i < byteCount; i++) { result[i] = bytes[position + i]; }
        return result;
    }
}

module.exports = Rfc2898DeriveBytes;
```

Comment: oh! and if you're using AESManaged, the Microsoft docs say it's Rijndael 128, but in reality it's not. Use Node's crypto 'aes-256-cbc' for that. Hoping this spares someone the time/pain I went through.