# How to check password in node.js from AspNetUsers .net core

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core

I have a database that used in .net core web site, now I need check login with node js
How to check password hash in node.js, I found a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706485/javascript-how-to-generate-rfc2898derivebytes-like-c) for doing that but doesn't work for .net core  AspNetUsers, only do in last asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as this post: [JavaScript: How to generate Rfc2898DeriveBytes like C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706485/javascript-how-to-generate-rfc2898derivebytes-like-c)

but for .net core need to change because in .net core ^1 for hashing use v3, so code should change to:

```
// The value stored in [dbo].[AspNetUsers].[PasswordHash]
    const hashedPwd =   "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAENX1Hdhgta05DYzYzVOI5kfv1mM0oc2OCIF8tKvNZeSTMWoczGZk+6yy9DMWtLeVQQ==";
    const hashedPasswordBytes = new Buffer(hashedPwd, 'base64');        
    const hexChar = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

    let salt_string = "";
    let storedSubKeyString = "";

    // build strings of octets for the salt and the stored key
    for (let i = 1; i < hashedPasswordBytes.length; i++) {
        if (i > 12 && i <= 28) {

            salt_string += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f]
        }
        if (i > 0 && i > 28) {
            storedSubKeyString += hexChar[(hashedPasswordBytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f] + hexChar[hashedPasswordBytes[i] & 0x0f];
        }
    }

    // password provided by the user        
    const password = 'password';       

    var nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync( 
            new Buffer(password), 
            new Buffer(salt_string, 'hex'), 10000, 256, 'SHA256');


    var derivedKeyOctets = nodeCrypto.toString('hex').toUpperCase();


    if (derivedKeyOctets.indexOf(storedSubKeyString) === 0) {
        return "passwords match!";
    } else {
        return "passwords DO NOT match!";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [node-password-hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-hash) (although it is deprecated) is one simple/great module which will get the password hashing done in easy steps for you.

It also provides functions for generating a hashed passwords and verifying a plain-text password against a hashed password. In addition to that as an additional security measure, a random salt is generated when the password is hashed. The hashed password is a combination of both the cryptographic algorithm that was used as well the salt, so all you have to do is to just verify a plain-text password is the hashed password itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, but i need a lib that check .net core hashed password