# Checking ASP.NET password hashes in Node.js with Passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have a ASP.NET database with user credentials and I want to use them with [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) on Node.

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25963810/3062017) I saw the code which I need to check the hashes, but how do I integrate that with Passport ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy to use module called [Passport-Local Mongoose](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose).

To implement another hash algorithm, I forked the project (it has the MIT license) and modified the specific lines.