# How do I set an auth header for all requests with jQuery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, digest-authentication

I have a custom webserver which handles digest auth.
I have a webclient which connects to the webserver and performs digest auth in javascript, i.e. without having the pop-up window.

**Client side**

To avoid such pop-up windows, which is always the case on 401 errors, the client requests data with a custom warning header

```
new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', urlToGet + "?" + Math.random(), false);
request.setRequestHeader("Warning","CustomRequest");
```

**Server side**

Whenever the webserver obtains a CustomRequest warning header, it replies with a custom HTTP code (406) and an auth header.

The client then parses the server header, creates the hashed auth string and I can identify. So far, so good (see also my previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934240/is-there-a-way-to-channel-some-http-server-events-into-a-single-javascript-funct) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821003/code-example-for-c-sharp-and-javascript-sha256-hashing) ).

Now that I have the good header I would like my browser to include it in every request I make, being it CSS

```
  background-image: url(IMAGE_URL);
```

or jquery

```
 $('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src=IMAGE_URL />')
```

or jquery / AJAX

```
 $.ajax({
            url: SOME_URL,
            // ...
        });
```

The latter is probably the simplest, given that I can use

```
beforeSend : function(req) {req.setRequestHeader('Authorization',authHeader);}
```

and that I know the authHeader.

Is it possible to use jquery/javascript to tell the browser "all requests from now on should have this authorization header?

The alternative would be to implement sessions on the webserver side, which is something that I'd gladly avoid.

Comment: Isn't that what cookies are meant for?

Comment: yes, but I thought that after an AJAX request the cookie would have been automatically set and that subsequent requests would have used it. This is not the case, am I missing something? Could I set the cookie by hand?