# String to UTF8 to SHA256 to BASE64

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, typescript

In C# I have the following code:

```
public static string GetHashCode(string p)
    {
        var a = new SHA256Managed();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(a.ComputeHash(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(p)));
    }
```

And I have to achieve the same thing in Javascript, I was trying the following but it gives different result:

```
btoa((CryptoJS.SHA256(this.toUTF8Array(this.settingsService.Password)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)));
```

What am I supposed to do, what is wrong?

Example output for string 'aaa' for:
C#:`1f9e1d76685d765aa3a6ff85dced2f0a04f612536df52696684aaa67787e6cdd`
Js:`NGVhNWM1MDhhNjU2NmU3NjI0MDU0M2Y4ZmViMDZmZDQ1Nzc3N2JlMzk1NDljNDAxNjQzNmFmZGE2NWQyMzMwZQ==`

Comment: Can you add example outputs of each?

Comment: Instead of one liners, do each step seperately so you can see exactly where the difference is.

Comment: i have added examples

Comment: i did it step by step and there is difference in computehash() part

Comment: Possibly have a look at this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559203/sha-256-hashes-different-between-c-sharp-and-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with CryptoJS but I think you are outputting hex which is not the same as base64.

This generates the same result as C# [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pqr8yh95/10/)

```
var utf8arr = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("apassword");
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(utf8arr);
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
console.log(base64);
```