# Matching Java SHA2 Output vs MySQL SHA2 Output

Tags: java, hash, sha256, sha2

When I reproduce a SHA2 hash via the following code:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
digest.digest("A".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

it gives me a byte array, which is: 85,-102,-22,-48,-126,100,-43,121,93,57,9,113,-116,-35,5,-85,-44,-107,114,-24,79,-27,85,-112,-18,-13,26,-120,-96,-113,-33,-3

But when I reproduce same hash via MySQL it gives me a string which is: 5cfe2cddbb9940fb4d8505e25ea77e763a0077693dbb01b1a6aa94f2

How can I convert tha Java's result so that I can compare it with MySQL's result?

Comment: Use a string formatter to convert the byte array to hex string

Comment: What do you mean with: `it gives me a byte array, which is:85-102-22-48-126100-...` how can a `byte[]` have values bigger than 127?

Comment: output format may cause misunderstanding. Here is the values seperated with a comma:
85,-102,-22,-48,-126,100,-43,121,93,57,9,113,-116,-35,5,-85,-44,-107,114,-24,79,-27,85,-112,-18,-13,26,-120,-96,-113,-33,-3

Comment: converting to hex string doesn't give the same value also.

Comment: ah, ok. So `85` (decimal) is `55` hex, your MySQL hash starts with `5c`, are you sure both are using the same algorithm?

Comment: Here is the result:

I thought these are the same:

MySQL: SHA2('A',224)
Java: ("SHA-256")


Obviously they were not the same. So it must be:

MySQL: SHA2('A',256)
Java: ("SHA-256")

Also this was useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680661/java-sha256-outputs-different-hash-to-php-sha256

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check out your DB result it looks like your initial hash is actually a SHA-224 not SHA-256:

```
mysql> SELECT SHA2("A", 224);
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| SHA2("A", 224)                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 5cfe2cddbb9940fb4d8505e25ea77e763a0077693dbb01b1a6aa94f2 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Instead of:

```
mysql> SELECT SHA2("A", 256);
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SHA2("A", 256)                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 559aead08264d5795d3909718cdd05abd49572e84fe55590eef31a88a08fdffd |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

From there you're on the right track you just need to convert the byte[] output to a hex string.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class TestSHA256 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] hash = digest.digest("A".getBytes("UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i: hash) {
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0XFF & i));
            }
            System.out.println(hexString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
559aead08264d5795d399718cdd5abd49572e84fe55590eef31a88a08fdffd
```

Answer (score 4):

`Integer.toHexString(0XFF & i)` must be replaced with `String.format("%02x", 0XFF & i)`, otherwise it only produces a 1 character output, while 2 characters are expected.