# Java how to do sha256 hashing equiavelent to php crypt function ? result is not the same?

Tags: java, php, hash, sha, sha256

I am using this http://raginggoblin.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/java-alternative-to-php-crypt-function/  for the equivalent of php crypt function or does it says here that it is...

But I have the same value in java and in php but the hashing result is different.. I was wondering if not hashing is different because its not executed the same way ? I post this two values to a WS.

```
JAVA:


 String doc_data="{\"table\":\"1048582\"}";
 String data="$5$rounds=5000$503$La071hYxZERff9GGq0cb.x2k96Xx25\/C4vxQztQ7B96";
 String result=Crypt.crypt(doc_data, data);

PHP: 
 $params['result'] = crypt($params['doc_data'], @$this->initdata['data']);
```

I logged it and I put the exact data in from POST... but the result is not the same.. There is no way to do this right ? or there is no equivalent?

Before that library I used Guava..but still not the same

```
public static String crypt_sha256(String password, String salt) {
        int iteration_count = 5000;
        HashFunction func = Hashing.sha256();
        HashCode result = func.hashString(salt + param1, Charsets.UTF_8);

        for (int i = 0; i < iteration_count; i++) {
            result = func.hashBytes(result.asBytes());
        }

        return salt + result.toString();

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680661/java-sha256-outputs-different-hash-to-php-sha256?rq=1 this might answer your question as well.

Comment: yes that's a good approach but its not used with SALT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, so far I tested a few library's and the Winner is Apache's Crypt.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html

```
public static String crpyt_sha256_apache(String param1, String salt) {

        return Crypt.crypt(param1, salt);
    }
```

Comment: "winner is"? so you mean it's providing the same output as php crypt does?